# WooCommerce - Trying to Make Uploaded Files links clickable in Backend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woo-Commerce plugin for my WordPress website. In this i am using calculators for receiving orders. Whenever user upload any file i am getting path regarding the file in backend like you can see in this link http://promo.inkgility.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Screenshot_2.png

Upload file: path shows for product
Now what i am trying to do is to make this link clickable but i am not able to find the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

please put this code in your file and it will be downloaded. create new file download.php and get this path on below link.

```
<a href="download.php?file=path/<?php echo row['file_name']?>">Download</a>
```

using below function your image will be start download.

```
<?php
function download_file( $fullPath ){

  // Must be fresh start
  if( headers_sent() )
    die('Headers Sent');

  // Required for some browsers
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

  // File Exists?
  if( file_exists($fullPath) ){

    // Parse Info / Get Extension
    $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
    $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
    $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

    // Determine Content Type
    switch ($ext) {
      case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
      case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
      case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
      case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
      case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
      case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
      case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg":
      case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
      default: $ctype="application/force-download";
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fullPath)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $fullPath );

  } else
    die('File Not Found');

}
?>
```

in also you can download this way.

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

Let me know once this code is working.

Comment: No it is not useful for me